# Notepad++ change all 'xx' for 'xx++'

Tags: notepad++

Have some way to numerate the following text

> ('xx', 'link 001'),
>
> ('xx', 'link 002'),
>
> ('xx', 'link 100');

to

> ('001', 'link 001'),
>
> ('002', 'link 002'),
>
> ('100', 'link 100'),

like a while

```
While($x = 001; $x <= 100) {
$xx == $x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your text is laid out **exactly** like you posted:

```
('xx', 'link 001'),

('xx', 'link 002'),

('xx', 'link 100');
```

The following Regex search should work:

Find:

```
'\w+', 'link (\d+)'
```

Replace:

```
'\1', 'link \1'
```

Breaking this down bit-by-bit for you,

`'` - searches for `'`
`\w` - searches for an alphanumeric character or an underscore.
`+` - instructs Notepad++ to find the preceding sequence one or more times. In combination with the `\w`, this looks for one or more alphanumeric characters/underscores. This will match your `xx`.
`'` - another `'`. So at this point, we're looking for `'`, followed by one or more alphanumeric characters, followed by `'`.
`, 'link` - another literal search, this time for a comma followed by a space followed by a `'` followed by the word `link` followed by a space.
`(` - starts a grouping. Anything between parentheses (`()`) can be later identified using `\1`, `\2`, etc. This one will be identified by `\1` since it's our first group.
`\d` - searches for a digit.
`+` - again, matches one or more of the preceding characters. So we're looking for one or more digits.
`)` - closes the grouping. `\1` will now hold the results of a search for one or more digits.
`'` - the final `'` in your text.

Now for the replace. This is much simpler. In a nutshell, it just takes the digits the "find" regex found and replaces the multi-character sequence with them, then puts everything else back the way it was.

`'` - another literal, the first `'`.
`\1` - holds the results of the multi-digit search the "find" regex used. So for `link 001`, this will hold `001`; for `link 002`, this will hold `002`; etc. Here's where the magic happens: the alphanumeric sequence found by `\w+` will be replaced by the digits `\d+` found.
`', 'link` - another literal. This will insert `', 'link`. Basically we're just putting back the text that was already there.
`\1` - the same multi-digit grouping the last `\2` was. Once again, `001` for `link 001`, `002` for `link 002`, etc. We're just replacing the number that was already there... with itself.
`'` - the closing `'`.

Comment: The links doesn't have the exactly number of 'xx', it's just an example

Comment: @Matheus If it has `'` followed by one or more alphanumeric characters followed by `'`, the Regex will match. Try the search and see what happens.